# Is there any difference between the noun "move" and "movement" in the sense of moving in a physical sense?

Tags: difference, nouns

Is there any difference between the noun *move* and *movement* in the sense of moving in a physical sense? For example:

> Today we are going to learn the vocabulary to do with body **movements**/**moves**.

Answer (score 2):

Movement is **physical motion** between points in space while move is the **act of moving**.

According Oxford advanced Learner's Dictionary:
"move" = a change of place or position.
"Movement" = an act of moving your body or part of the body.
As well as, the collocations of movement are "**hand/eye movement**".

Therefore, movement is more suitable for your example.

Comment: Yes, but what about body movements, like shruging, head tilting? Why they dont call them body moves?

Comment: Because the body, as such, does not move. A "body move" would be, for example, in a dance or fight in which the body itself changes its absolute position. The change of position of the head or the shoulders does not move the body's general position.