# What is the semantic difference between “movement” and “moving”?

Tags: gerunds, verbal-noun

I noticed that “movement is slow” makes sense, but “moving is slow” doesn’t make sense.

I know “movement” is action, but I wonder what gerund “moving” means.

If there is sentence “her moving is important,” what does “important” modify?

Comment: I think _moving_ refers to the fact of something being moved rather than the action. "He was annoyed by her moving his spectacles."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Moving*** is the action you perform when you move. ***Movement*** is the result of that action. As a gerund, *moving* will refer to the *fact that someone moves (something)*:

> e.g.
>
> - ***Moving** [the fact that you have moved]* from A to B was a smart decision.

or a more concrete example

> It scares me, but then I notice her *moving* *[the fact that she is moving]* backwards... ([*Moving*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bdJBDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=%22her%20moving%22&source=bl&ots=u2Aoj4FzmS&sig=ACfU3U1uiVS-WeyIi-cGopcDIYD9amtK3A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiaqZT_iOfxAhUWRkEAHXbwBe0Q6AEwFXoECAsQAw#v=onepage&q=%22her%20moving%22&f=false) by J P Walker)

*Moving* can also refer to the placement of something in a new place. For example:

> *The **moving** of* the Mona Lisa: This Wednesday, amid huge fanfare, the Mona Lisa is to be unveiled in her new home in the Louvre. ([Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/moving-mona-lisa-530771.html))

If you said "*the movement of Mona Lisa*", it would mean that the painting came to life and started moving! Never happened till now, unless you speak about "*[Beauties Of The Past Brought To Life (AI Animated)](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beauty%20to%20life%20ai)*".

In fact *movement* is much closer to the noun *[move](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/move)* than to the gerundial noun *moving.* But this would be the topic of a [different question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/238586/is-there-any-difference-between-the-noun-move-and-movement-in-the-sense-of-m#:%7E:text=Movement%20is%20physical%20motion%20between,or%20part%20of%20the%20body.).

Before finishing, I would just like to add that ***moving*** can also be used as an adjective (so it is a present participle meaning ***that moves/can move***):

> A moving object is one that moves:
>
> - a ***moving*** *target*
> - ***moving*** *parts* in a
>   machine ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/moving))